# SED Replace strings with file contents

Tags: linux, unix

I have file with environment variables.

File with e.variables has the following contents:

```
STACK=OVERFLOW
PORT=3000
```

My .txt file has the following contents:

```
First variable: STACK 
Second variable: PORT
```

I want to replace `STACK` and `PORT` in my .txt file using the values from file with environment variables.

Result:

```
First variable: OVERFLOW
Second variable: 3000
```

I tried use the SED, but without a success.

```
sed -i -e 's/STACK/????/g' .txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the variables in file1 are **exported**, you can do this which requires GNU sed for the `s/pattern/replacement/e` command

```
$ cat file1
export STACK=OVERFLOW
export PORT=3000

$ cat file2
First variable: STACK
Second variable: PORT

$ . file1

$ sed -i.bak -r 's/^([^:]+: *)(.+)/printf "%s%s\\n" "\1" "$\2"/e' file2

$ cat file2
First variable: OVERFLOW
Second variable: 3000
```

Comment: Thanks you for help!

Comment: What if I want to replace my strings without ":" char? For example: First variable equal STACK and second variable equal PORT?

Comment: Them you'll make slight adjustments to the regex and the printf format string.